# Next biggest value or next unique value in VARCHAR field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've run into a rather unique request in a system I work on that's running on a T-SQL db. I have a table that looks something like this in its most basic form:

```
create table Merchants (
    ID          int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
    PartnerID   int,
    ExternalRef varchar(10),
    Name        varchar(MAX)
)
```

`ExternalRef` is a `varchar(10)` field in which we carry a reference number provided by one of a number of external parties. It is therefor only unique within the scope defined by the `PartnerID` value.

The problem I'm having now is that one partner doesn't have values they could provide us with and wants us to generate values for them. That's easy enough, I could use incrementing integer values and convert them to varchar. So before assigning a new value I could simply do a `select max(ExternalRef) where PartnerID = @PartnerID`, convert to integer, add 1 to the value and convert it back to varchar. In fact, the DBMS will do all of that conversion implicitly and something like this should work fine:

```
select @NewRef = max(ExternalRef)+1
from Merchants
where PartnerID = @PartnerID
```

But my concern is, what if one of the values for that partner is an alphanumeric value and gets returned by the `select max(ExternalRef)` call? The above approach will obviously fail in an ugly way and I'm not aware of a way to "increment" an alphanumeric string, whatever that even means.

So I need a way to come up with a unique `varchar(10)` value that does not already exist in the table. I could generate a random value, check if it is already in the table and repeat if it is but I'm not mad about that approach either. If there was something I could use in the `where` clause to limit the results to values that are numeric only, that would also have worked but I can't think of an elegant way to do that. Something like:

```
select @NewRef = coalesce(max(ExternalRef), 0)+1
from Merchants
where PartnerID = @PartnerID
    and ExternRef is numeric
```

Would anyone have suggestions on how I can generate the "next biggest" varchar value on a field or any unique value without taking up too much processing?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I've figured it out. Turns out my imagined "is numeric" condition wasn't all that far fetched. As of SQL Server 2008 there is the [ISNUMERIC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql) function. So to get the varchar representation of the next biggest integer only value in a varchar field, here's what I'm doing now:

```
select @NewRef = coalesce(max(ExternalRef), 0)+1
from Merchants
where PartnerID = @PartnerID
    and ISNUMERIC(ExternRef) = 1
```

Comment: `IsNumeric()` is, to use the technical term, [hinky](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2011/07/26/goodbye-isnumeric-hell/). You might want to look at `Try_Parse()` or `Try_Convert()` instead. Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Comment: Thanks @HABO, I've added the SQL Server tag. I'm never sure about the version tag as this question doesn't pertain to any particular version of SQL Server. Sure, the version that we use would dictate which answers are useful but I was hoping for a version agnostic answer.

As for TRY_CONVERT(), it looks great, thanks. Unfortunately it doesn't work on our server (2014). Seems to be because the db in question is running under compatibility mode 100. I have no idea why but I'm not about to go make changes to that. I'll raise it with our DBA though.

Answer (score 0):

1. add computed persisted column or view with new column - use `ISNUMERIC` deterministic function with `CASE` and `CAST` or use scalar function with schemabinding

   ```
   alter table Merchants 
   add ExternRefNbr as (cast(case when isnumeric(ExternalRef) = 1 then ExternalRef end as int)) persisted
   ```
2. create index on new column
3. use column

Comment: Is the point of this to make the ISNUMERIC(ExternRef) = 1 clause more efficient?